# Error Create Store View for each Magento 2 language

Tags: magento2

I have installed the following language packs:

```
php bin/magento setup: static-content: deploy -f nl_NL
php bin/magento setup: static-content: deploy -f fr_FR
php bin/magento setup: static-content: deploy -f de_DE
```

Once the deploy is done, the cache cleaned and reindexed, I have created a Store View for each language but when I activate them and change in my store to the selected language I get the following error:

[image]

Can someone help me understand what the problem is please? Because I can not find out why it is not working for me.

thank you very much!

Comment: is this in local?

Comment: no, it's on my server, do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: did you found any solution ?

Comment: Not for now, I have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Remove cache folder and others by using commend 
Go to magento project root folder

```
sudo rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/* pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/
```

And then run commends

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 

php bin/magento setup: static-content: deploy -f nl_NL
php bin/magento setup: static-content: deploy -f fr_FR
php bin/magento setup: static-content: deploy -f de_DE
```

Hope it will works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but, still not working, some other idea?

Comment: Can you please share the error log? or can you share your dev server info(if you have ) so that i can investigate the issue.

Comment: Which of the logos do you want me to show you?

Comment: exception.log . if it shows same log? please check top-home.phtml file is exits in your project. If exits then check file permission is ok or not.

Comment: In the log file there is nothing, and the file that exists in my theme and I put 777 permissions to the file and the folders that host it but it remains the same

Comment: Can you share your magento admin and ftp access? so that i can investigate.